# Android: put URL code in AsyncTask

Tags: android, url, android-asynctask

How I can place the text below in `AsyncTask`? My problem is that by placing the code directly I get an error `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I need any help please. Thanks

```
try {
    URL myFileUrl = new URL ("http://.../cercanias.png");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getCacheDir() + "cercanias.png");
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagenNitida);

    imageView.setImageFile(getCacheDir() + "cercanias.png");

    out.close();

    if (savedInstanceState != null &&
            savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SCALE) &&
            savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_X) &&
            savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_Y)) {

        imageView.setScaleAndCenter(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_SCALE), 
                new PointF(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_X), 
                        savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y)));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Put it in doInBackground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

     protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
    // Long running task - say processing of each passed string

     URL myFileUrl = new URL ("http://.../cercanias.png");
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
     conn.setDoInput(true);
     conn.connect();

     InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getCacheDir() + "cercanias.png");
     bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
     out.close();
    return 0;
}


protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
    Log.d("TestP", "AsyncTask returned : " + result);
 SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagenNitida);

imageView.setImageFile(getCacheDir() + "cercanias.png");


if (savedInstanceState != null &&
        savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SCALE) &&
        savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_X) &&
        savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_Y)) {

    imageView.setScaleAndCenter(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_SCALE), 
            new PointF(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_X), 
                    savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y)));
}
}
```

Comment: and savedInstanceState? savedInstanceState is bundle of my activity

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: There are three steps to an AsyncTask, preExecute(), postExecute() and doInBackground. The names are self explanatory. preExecute() for everything which has to be done before execution, postExecute for everything after the execution and doInBackground for the process which is time consuming.

Simple example:

```
public class HeavyProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //After execution execute this
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Before execution do this, like init a progress dialog
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Do the time consuming work here
            return "";
        }
    }
```

now in your case: create a function with all your code:

```
public void timeTask(){

try {
    URL myFileUrl = new URL ("put your URL here");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getCacheDir() + "cercanias.png");
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagenNitida);

    imageView.setImageFile(getCacheDir() + "cercanias.png");

    out.close();


    }
} catch (IOException e) {
}

}
```

Then call the timeTask() function from  doInBackground();

Comment: and savedInstanceState? savedInstanceState is bundle of my activity

Comment: That goes into the onCreate(),or in the postExecute, which ever is preferable, my bad! Make sure you do not do any I/O in doInBackground. That will come crashing down.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

                try {
                    URL myFileUrl = new URL("http://.../cercanias.png");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getCacheDir() +File.separator+ "cercanias.png");
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    out.close();
                    conn.disconnect();
                    bm.recycle();

                    return "cercanias.png";

                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenNitida);

                    imageView.setImageFile(getCacheDir() +File.separator+ result);

                    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SCALE) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_X)
                            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_Y)) {

                        imageView.setScaleAndCenter(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_SCALE),
                                new PointF(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_X), savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y)));
                    }
                }
            };
        }.execute();
```

Comment: and savedInstanceState? savedInstanceState is bundle of my activity

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to break this code into portions and fit them into AsyncTask :

```
public class checkGB_status_Async extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
try {
    URL myFileUrl = new URL ("http://.../cercanias.png");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    return bm;
} catch (IOException e) {
}
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getCacheDir() + "cercanias.png");
    result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView =       (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagenNitida);

    imageView.setImageFile(getCacheDir() + "cercanias.png");

    out.close();

    if (savedInstanceState != null &&
            savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SCALE) &&
            savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_X) &&
            savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_Y)) {

    imageView.setScaleAndCenter(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_SCALE), 
            new PointF(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_X), 
                    savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y)));
}
}
```

Comment: and savedInstanceState? savedInstanceState is bundle of my activity